# Call nested function to same object

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am developing a plugin, after add object to the plugin i want to call some events to same object from outside, how can i do that

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    jQuery.fn.pluginname = function (options) {
        var set = $.extend({
            opacity: 0.5             
        }, options);

        //if(options.type)

        var cdiv = this;
        cdiv.css("opacity",set.opacity);

        function callthis()
        {
            cdiv.css("display","none");
        }
    }
})(jQuery);


jQuery("#first").pluginname({opacity:0.5});

jQuery("#second").pluginname({opacity:0.5});

// call this function later

jQuery("#first").pluginname("callthis");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to have your plugin accept "methods" as string arguments, e.g.:

```
jQuery("#first").pluginname("callThis");
```

Internally in the plugin, you route that request to the function.

Normally you'd also want to store the options used initially somewhere other than just in the closure; `data` is useful for that.

And you normally have a `"destroy"` method to remove the plugin from elements.

So:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            // Determine options
            var opts = $.extend({
                opacity: 0.5             
            }, options);

            // Remember them
            this.data("pluginname", opts);

            // Initial stuff
            this.css("opacity", opts.opacity);
        },

        callThis: function(opts) {
            // Use 'opts' if relevant
            this.css("display","none");
        },

        destroy: function(opts) {
            this.removeData("pluginame");
            this.css("display", "").css("opacity", "");
        }
    };

    jQuery.fn.pluginname = function (options) {
        var method, args;

        // Method?
        if (typeof options === "string") {
            // Yes, grab the name
            method = options;

            // And arguments (we copy the arguments, then
            // replace the first with our options)
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

            // Get our options from setup call
            args[0] = this.data("pluginname");
            if (!args[0]) {
                // There was no setup call, do setup with defaults
                methods.init.call(this);
                args[0] = this.data("pluginname");
            }
        }
        else {
            // Not a method call, use init
            method = "init";
            args = [options];
        }

        // Do the call
        methods[method].apply(this, args);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rata/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/rata/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    jQuery.fn.pluginname = function (options) {
        var set = $.extend({
            opacity: 0.5             
        }, options);

        //if(options.type)
        if(typeof options == function){
        return function callthis()
        {
            cdiv.css("display","none");
        }
        } else{
        return function(){
        var cdiv = this;
        cdiv.css("opacity",set.opacity);
        }
        }


    }
})(jQuery);
```